# Android tablets can't leverage layout in sw600dp folder

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

Our Xamarin Android app keeps crashing for a few users who are on the following devices:

- Samsung Chromebook Plus
- Samsung Galaxy Tab E 8

Here is the NotFoundException crash:

> Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable:
>   RPR.Mobile.Shared.ForensicsException: DataFragmentBase - OnCreateView
>   - Inflate of layoutResourceId 2130903336 in fragment RPR.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.Ambient.TabletAmbientCompositeFragment
>   errored: Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f030128   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>
> [0x0000c] in :0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallObjectMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
>   <0bfa1a9f6d754384ac2bad519852e6f9>:0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod
>   (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self,
>   Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002a] in
>   <0bfa1a9f6d754384ac2bad519852e6f9>:0    at
>   Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (System.Int32 resource,
>   Android.Views.ViewGroup root, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x0005a]
>   in <354f190b75174df881c91c689800754e>:0    at
>   RPR.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.DataFragmentBase`1[T].OnCreateView
>   (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup
>   container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00034] in
>   <8295e3c148c048c688eef3a452730b7a>:0    --- End of managed
>   Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException stack trace ---
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f030128   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)   at
>
> android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2124)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1118)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)  at
>   md5413ac457e5f8728857d33bbead6e898a.DataFragmentBase_1.n_onCreateView(Native
>   Method)   at
>   md5413ac457e5f8728857d33bbead6e898a.DataFragmentBase_1.onCreateView(DataFragmentBase_1.java:41)

Matching that id in Resource.designer.cs, the resource that can't be found is:

```
// aapt resource value: 0x7f030128
public const int TabletHomePropertyList = 2130903336;
```

This layout file is in the sw600dp and sw600dp-land folders. So it seems that even though these two devices are tablets, their shortest side isn't at least 600dp. I don't have access to these devices, how can I figure out the appropriate sw***dp value for them?

More concerning, my code that checks whether it's a tablet or not and then loads this tablet-specific layout is derived from checking a dimens value in values-sw600dp.

```
<bool name="is_large_tablet">true</bool>
```

So it's only trying to load the layout-sw600dp layout file if a dimen exists in values-sw600dp. That should work... Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Probably not the answer you want, but Android devices are so diverse that there isn't a great way to determine `isTablet` or even `isLargerTablet`. Instead the best way to determine this factor is by `Screen Size` and `Device Features`. `sw` refers to the smallestWidth of a screen. It would be worthwhile to get screen dimensions on these devices to properly provide qualifiers. It sounds like you might want to remove that type of functionality with your `dimens` value.

Comment: According to https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_e_8_0-7879.php the Galaxy Tab E 8 has a smallest width of ~677dp, so I don't think the error is that it can't see the `layout-sw600dp` directory.

Comment: I wonder if it's a Xamarin bug then... Since the resource file is definitely in layout-sw600dp.

Comment: @JonDouglas I'm already determining it's tablet by screen size, as I'm setting the threshold for our tablet layouts at 600dp for the shortest side. Or do you mean to check for device features (e.g. if it can call) in combination with the screen size? In any case, I'm concerned that this is a Xamarin bug. Ben has confirmed that the device is over 600dp, the values-sw600dp dimen is being loaded, and yet the layout-sw600dp file is not.

Comment: The stack trace suggests java code, I would have to see a reproduction project and run it on an emulator that has the problematic dimensions. Can you compile that together and file an issue here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues Please include instructions for the emulator creation that shows this failure.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to either of these devices, nor can I find matching emulators. I'm only seeing these crashes in our hockeyapp logs, and only for a few users. I guess I'll have to either chalk it up to a bug that I can't do anything about, or move all of our tablet-only layouts into the main layout folder.

Comment: You don't need access to these devices per-say. Create a new AVD that matches these devices.via a custom hardward profile or a similar existing device definition. I don't personally believe this is a Xamarin bug, but rather yet another Android oddity. The only way to figure that out is by [isolating the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).